# Doctrine 2 orm:convert-d1-schema command missing in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm on windows 7 64 bits.

I will have to do the migration of a Symfony 1.4 website.

I found the command `orm:convert-d1-schema` to convert the Symfony 1.4 DB Schema to Symfony 2.

But this command is not implemented in Symfony 2.4

http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=33149
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1442

I tried to install the doctrine 2 CLI to do the converting but I got errors and stopped trying this as this is probably a bad idea.

Do you know how I can get this command working on Symfony ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use all the `orm:*` [commands available](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/tools.html#command-overview) in Doctrine 2 you will need to configure/setup the [Commandline Tools](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html).

If you've followed a standard symfony 2 project setup you probably have a `bin/` directory under your project root. Inside that folder you should file two files `doctrine` and `doctrine.php`.

You should use this `doctrine` executable or probably the `doctrine.php` since you're on Windows instead of the `app/console` one.
This way you'll be able to use the Doctrine ORM commands directly instead of the "alias provided by symfony" for them.

If you have further questions regarding this let me know.

Regards,